# allow all users to read/write any files/folders on 2nd drive regardless of who created it in linux

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, hard-drive, samba, mount

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I've got a mount point called `/files` that is owned by `root`, the group is `plugdev` and I've given the group write permission. I used some of the information in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive to set this up. Specifically the following commands:

```
sudo chgrp plugdev /files
sudo chmod g+w /files
```

All the users on the machine are also part of `plugdev`.

I've mounted a drive that has 1 `ext4` partition to it.

At this point both `user1` and `user2` **can** create files/folders in `/files`. But, if `user1` creates a file or folder in `/files` then `user2` **cannot** modify it or create files in it.

**I am wondering, how can I make it so all users can read/write (and, where applicable, execute) any/all files/folders created in `/files` regardless of who created it.**

If it matters, `/files` is also a Samba share that is mounted on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just what you need. This question was answered already over there.

You need setfacl + chmod

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Thanks. But I'm wondering why we need ACL if we set the group sticky bit and all users are part of the group.

Comment: According to that answer, it allows you to set default create permissions on files in the specified directory.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions on the files you're creating probably don't have write permission for group. If you set the `fmask` (for files) and the `dmask` (for directories) in your `/etc/fstab` this should fix the issue.

`fmask` might be something like `113`, for default permissions of `664` or `rw-rw-r-`

`dmask` might be something like `002`, for default permissions of `775` or `rwxrwxr-x`.

Remember directories need execute permission to access them.